# executable size compiled by gcc

Tags: gcc, filesize

Hello experts please answer my following query.
For the size of binary file 'test' I used the following commands in linux fedora and compiled by gcc compiler.

```
$ll -h test

-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user user 4.3M Feb  8 11:17 test

$size test

text       data     bss     dec     hex filename

891714   244788   26664 1163166  11bf9e test
```

My question is which is the right command to know the size of executable file 'test'? why two commands shows different results ?

Answer (score 2):

The `ls` program gives you the file size, 4.3M (actually, 4.5M because `-h` uses the wrong prefix… but this is not relevant).

The `sizes` program gives the section sizes.  Not all sections are included, which is why it is smaller.  Your program probably has debug information included, which is not printed out by `sizes`.

Comment: I think you mean the `size` program, not `sizes`.

Comment: Yes,  it was compiled with -g flag. After compiling without -g option, ls -l command shows the size of executable as 1499004 and 'size' command shows 1163166, but still there is difference. I have a hardware board which has RAM of only 2MB, that means can't I load the executable compiled with -g option which shows the size of executable as 4.3MB?

Comment: @user3899508: Sounds like you want `strip`.  But there are a lot of reasons why an executable might be large.

Answer (score 1):

Your file `test` probably contains debug info, which `size` does not report. `ll -h` is more correct to get the actual file size, but the `-h` option has abbreviated it for readability. You can get the exact file size with `ls -l` (`ll`) or `stat`.

Read the documentation for `size`, `objdump`, and `readelf` to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Run following command :

```
size .\test.exe
```

Output ::

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename   
 9400    1576    1004   11980    2ecc .\test.exe
```